# Custom getter for the whole object, not only properties?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, setter, getter

I can use `get` for individual properties, like this:

```
function MyObjectConstructor() {
    this._internalValueOne = 'foo';
    this._internalValueTwo = 'bar';
}

MyObjectConstructor.prototype = {
    get usefulValueOne() {
        return this._internalValueOne + 'baz';
    },
    get usefulValueTwo() {
        return this._internalValueTwo + 'baz';
    }
}

var myObject = new MyObjectConstructor();
```

Now `myObject.usefulValueOne` gives `'foobaz'` and `myObject.usefulValueTwo` gives `'barbaz'`. Can I somehow use `get` to make sure that `myObject` (and any other object based on `MyObjectConstructor`) also returns an object like `{usefulValueOne: 'foobaz', usefulValueTwo: 'barbaz'}`? Or is there some other preferred way to do this?

Naturally I also wonder the same thing for `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
function MyObjectConstructor() {
    this._internalValueOne = 'foo';
    this._internalValueTwo = 'bar';
}

MyObjectConstructor.prototype = {
    get usefulValueOne() {
        return this._internalValueOne + 'baz';
    },
    get usefulValueTwo() {
        return this._internalValueTwo + 'baz';
    },
    get showProt(){
        var B = {};
        for (var i in this){
            if (i.hasOwnProperty && (i !== 'showProt')){
                B[i] = this[i];
           }
        }
        return B;
    }
}
var myObject = new MyObjectConstructor();
```

now myObject.showProp will show you an object with all properties (including privates, you should remove them)